# EmberJS Nested routes pictures doesn't load

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have ember.js application.

root
/app
/components
/templates
/gallery
application.hbs
gallery.hbs
index.hbs
app.js
index.html
router.js
/public
/assets
--folders with pictures inside which contains pictures

I have 4200/gallery

Which load up pictures without ANY problems.

But in 4200/gallery/nested

It gives me:

GET http://localhost:4200/assets/bb/1.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Where is the problem please ? What do I do wrong it's frustrating that it does load without a problem on gallery page but it doesn't laod up on nested route.

It keeps me away from finishing this project.

Thank you for any answers.

Comment: When you visit `/gallery`, what’s an example `src` for an image that renders properly? And how does that compare to a `src` for an image that fails to load on the subroute?

Comment: It's the same as subroute

/assets/Folder/img.jpg

Comment: you sure it starts with an `/`?

Comment: I tried, with slash and aswell without as it's supposed. 

When I build not nested route, it shows up. I wanted to build nested routes because I think it's better practice.

But decided not tu and just keep it simple. 

But if someone will come up with the solution I will be very happy.